# Maths and Economics

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, economics, microlocal-analysis

The function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1\,,\qquad &\text{if $|x| \le 1$}\\
2x\,, &\text{if $|x|>1$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Is this function convex and contionous on
a) [-1, infinity)
b) [-1,1]
c) [-infinity,1)
d)none
what I think is this function is convex

Comment: If you can prove it is convex, then you are done as convexity implies Lipschitzianity (which is way stronger than lone continuity)

Comment: It would be interesting to know where economics fits in this question, as well.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, convexity implies Lipschitzianity which in turn implies continuity. Then you have
$$\text{convexity} \implies \text{continuity}$$
and 
$$\text{not continuous} \implies \text{not convex}$$
Clearly it can happen that your given function is continuous  but not convex.

---

Is your function continuous? Given its definition, can it have discontinuity points? If so, where?

---

Or is it convex? For any $x, y$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ does

$$f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$

hold?

---

As a starter, can you answer at least one of those two questions?